# Working usage example of Handlebars Intl with jsreport

Tags: jsreport

I'm looking for working example of how to apply locale for a report inside the jsreport. I'm using handlebars for template. 
I've installed  handlebars-intl into docker with jsreport by
npm install handlebars-intl

And connect it in my template like that,

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars');

var HandlebarsIntl = require('handlebars-intl');
HandlebarsIntl.registerWith(handlebars);
```

When I'm using it in html template I want to setup locale to nl-NL
I've tried to setup it like that right in html

```
  {{#intl locales="nl-NL"}}
            <td class="grand total">Totaal:</td>
            <td class="total">{{formatNumber totalAmount}}</td>
            <td class="total"></td>
            <td class="total">{{formatNumber vatAmount}}</td>
            <td class="total">{{total totalAmount vatAmount}}</td>
            {{/intl}}
```

FormatNumber apply format for en-EN locale, but non for nl. I've tried to use different locales it seems that it doesn't work at all. On the Handlebars Intl tutorial page I found example

```
var intlData = {
    locales: 'en-US'
}

var context = {
    price: 1000
};

var html = template(context, {
    data: {intl: intlData}
});
```

But when i trying to apply it i've got an error

```
Error while executing templating engine. template is not defined
```

I'm not strong in js (more .net) And can't understand how it works, and how to apply it properly. Please help by share working example, or point me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I don't understand the people who set minus because they don't know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with node.js is not including localization by default. 
I had to customize run script and add package to node 
My Dockefile looks like

```
FROM jsreport/jsreport:2.6.0-full
RUN npm i handlebars-intl full-icu --save
COPY jsreport.config.json /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY run.sh /app
```

Also I need to modify run.sh script to run node with supporting locales

```
node --icu-data-dir=node_modules/full-icu "/app/server.js"
```

After that locales start working.  Hope it helps someone else